# New AMD Ryzen build Ubuntu 18.04 complete freeze

Tags: 18.04, freeze, amd-ryzen

I am new Ubuntu. I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LPS on newly built machine (specs below). The screen randomly keeps freezing (also when idle). The system is completely or partially irresponsive to keyboard/mouse, while the fans keep running and only reset/ turning off violently helps.

Since I am new to Ubuntu, I do not know where to start looking for the problem...

Machine:

AMD Ryzen 7 2700X

Gigabyte B450 Aorus Pro

MSI Armor Radeon RX 570

Corsair Vengeance Ram

Corsair CX550M PSU

Samsung 970 Evo

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First make sure your BIOS/firmware is up to date for the mb and SSD. Which kernel are you using?The latest available would be the one to use *don't use 18.04.1, use the latest).

Comment: BIOS is up to date, I use Ubuntu version 18.04.4 with kernel 5.3.0-40-generic

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution for this?

Comment: yeah, I disabled C6 state in the bios and set idle current to 'typical' and never had a problem again